# Svg gradient, override other svg too

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg, svg-filters

basically I have two SVG and If I try to change the color of the second one it doesn't change, If I do to the first one, it change the color of both the SVG.

In the example below, if you duplicate the circle and change the color in the `stop` :

```
 <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FFE009" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#5eaefd" />
    </linearGradient>
```

you will see this behaviour, the only way I find to fix this is to `id` for each svg, but it's not really convenient, especially if you want to have multiple of them.

Is there a fix or a workaround?

https://codepen.io/plava/pen/BjavpN

Comment: If your gradients are identical then you only need one copy, otherwise  use unique ids, anything duplicates make things invalid and cause the problems you're seeing.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I just fixed it using a dynamic id I pass as a prop

Answer (score 0):

You can try use separate svg file with gradients, and setup gradient in css

```
<style>
    .svg-1 {
        stroke: url(#gradient);
    }
    .svg-2 {
        stroke: url(#gradient2);
    }
</style>


<svg class="svg-1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="47"  stroke-width="6" fill="none" transform='rotate(90 50 50)'/>
</svg>
<svg class="svg-2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="47" stroke-width="6" fill="none" transform='rotate(90 50 50)'/>
</svg>

<svg>
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#00bc9b" />
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#fff" />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="gradient2" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#00bc9b" />
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#000" />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
</svg>
```